# How can I properly and efficiently preform a Sized Item Grid Based Sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, inventory

So I have a 2D Grid like so...

```
// Y: Size 13 For Each Column
// X: Size 9 For Each Row
vector<vector<int>> grid;
```

It is initialized with empty items into a 13 height, 9 width grid.

Imagine we have the following the grid populated with the following items...

1. 3 Width 5 Height item at X=0, Y=0.
2. 2 Width 5 Height item at X=3, Y=0.
3. 2 Width 5 Height item at X=5, Y=0.
4. 2 Width 5 Height item at X=7, Y=0.
5. 2 Width 5 Height item at X=0, Y=5.
6. 2 Width 5 Height item at X=2, Y=5.
7. 2 Width 5 Height item at X=4, Y=5.
8. 3 Width 5 Height item at X=6, Y=5.

Now imagine we need a sort function that will re-organize the inventory into the best possible, most space efficient, layout. This is what I need... Although I'm not certain how to accomplish this...

Currently I preform a sort using the following function and function call...

```
bool SortBySize(const InventoryItem &lhs, const InventoryItem &rhs)
{
    Item itemL = GetItemByName(lhs.item);
    Item itemR = GetItemByName(rhs.item);

    return itemL.cells() > itemR.cells();
}
// In Main()...
sort(m_items_list.begin(), m_items_list.end(), SortBySize);
```

However, this arrangement causes some Items to not be moved/sorted because after the re-order there is not enough room for that item. In this specific case the 2 3x5 items are stored first, then all the 2x5 items follow them. However, the grid will not fit one of the 2x5 items with the new sorted order, which causes some unexpected behavior...

Answer (score 2):

You can think of this as a bin packing problem.  This problem is an [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) and as such there is no known efficient way to locate a solution in the first place.  One way you can solve this is to start off with the biggest piece in the top left corner (0,0).  Then with the 2 remaining pieces do the same thing.  There is nice [example](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/) of this process at Code inComplete.  It deals with packing CSS sprites but should be easily modified for this solution in C++.